# Prove that f is onto iff h o f = k o f implies h = k.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f: A \to  B$ be a function. Prove that $f$ is onto iff $h \circ  f = k \circ f$ implies $h=k$, for every set $C$ and all choices of functions $h: B \to  C$ and $k: B \to C$.

My works here:

Please check my answer.

Since f is onto, for all y is in B, there exists at least one x which is in A, such that f(x) = y. Suppose h and k are onto so we have for all z is in C, there exists at least one y is in B such that h(y) = z and k(y) = z. (Is that okay to assume that h and k are onto?)
So, now we have h(f(x)) = z and k(f(x)) = z by substituting f(x) into y.
It implies (h o f)(x) = (k o f)(x) since they have the same element, z. 
It implies h o f = k o f therefore, h equal to k.

Conversely, since h o f = k o f, h(f(x_1)) = k(f(x_2)) = z , z is in C and x_1, x_2 are in A. 
We know that h o f: A -> C and k o f: A -> C. 
(h o f)(x_1) = z
(k o f)(x_2) = z
.
.
?

Sorry I don't know how to use math symbols in here. Hm.....

Comment: So how far are you? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how to edit my post. I want to show my works but, I can't find the edit button.

Comment: There is no reason you should assume $h$ or $k$ are onto.

Comment: So I can't assume h or k are onto right? Then my proof is wrong.

Comment: But is it really wrong to just assume that h and k are onto here?...

Comment: You would be proving something weaker than what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exactly write down a proof formally (or how to bring the things I know together)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371593/how-to-exactly-write-down-a-proof-formally-or-how-to-bring-the-things-i-know-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suppose that $f$ is onto, and suppose $h,k$ are such that $hf=kf$. Pick $y\in B$. Then there exists $x\in A$ such that $y=f(x)$. But since $hf=kf$, we have that $h(y)=hf(x)=\cdots$?

Now, suppose $f$ is not onto. Then there is some $y'\in B$ such that for no $x\in A$ we have $f(x)=y$. Let $C=\{a,b\}$ for two arbitrary $a,b$. Define $h(y)=a$ for $y\in B$ and let $k(y)=a$ if $y\neq y'$ and $k(y)=b$ if $y=y'$. What happens now?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try it now.

Comment: Pedro, how should I finish this? I have to find that $k\circ f\neq h\circ f$?

Comment: Actually, we have that $k\circ f= h\circ f$ and $k\neq h$.

Comment: @Dunck Your last comment is right.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $h \circ f = k \circ f$ as "$h$ and $k$ agree on the image of $f$", that is to say that for any $y$ in the image of $f$, $h(y) = k(y)$.

Surjectivity is a condition on the image of $f$.

I claim that this perspective makes "surjective implies right-cancellable" easy, and for the other direction you just have to show that when $f$ is *not* surjective, you will be able to find functions that agree on the image of $f$ but don't agree everywhere. (Think indicator functions, for example).